# Pulseaudio push RTP stream in aLaw or uLaw format

Tags: audio-streaming, multicast, pulseaudio

I have a problem with RTP stream by PulseAudio. If i try to use codex like s16 or float 32 I can hear a stream in VCL player. But I have IP speaker what approve only PCMA, PCMU and G.722.
I know G.722 is not supported so I didn't use that, but when I use a aLaw or uLaw in PulseAudio default.pa:

```
load-module module-rtp-send source=alsa_output.default.monitor destination_ip=239.239.14.1 port=48000 format=alaw loop=1
```

I get this:

```
E: [pulseaudio] module-rtp-send.c: Specified sample type not compatible with RTP
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-rtp-send" (argument: "source=alsa_output.default.monitor destination_ip=239.239.14.1 port=48000 format=alaw loop=1"): initialization failed.
```

But if i change there format on s16 or another exept uLaw, it work, but only in VCL. Not on speakers

I don't know how to make it work. I check in PulseAudio documentation this codex is supported.

I tried to make a changes inside /etc/pulse/default.pl and /etc/pulse/daemon.conf for make alaw as default codex, but it didn't work too. It looks like PulseAudio can't set alaw on audio output for multicast